# DocuSign transparent tab background via API

Tags: docusignapi

Using the DocuSign web interface we can get transparent tab backgrounds.

But through the API I am only able to set TextTab font color -- background color seems to default to 'white'. has anyone had any luck?

[image]

Comment: Both tabs are TextTabs -- one created through the API, the other through the interface. When you say data tab, you're referring to any tab type? And what is document markup?

Comment: [EDITED]   IMO the DocuSign data tab always has a WHITE background when created via the API or via the web app/interface. Once you finish signing, the final PDF will result have a transparent background, only burning the text entered onto the document.

Comment: awesome, thanks yeah you're totally right! thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as [Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1204405/luis-scott) says -- after signing, the white background is removed:

[image]